# Hyper-V Windows 10 virtual machine continuously crashing with memory management blue screen

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, hyper-v, bsod, sysinternals

I am trying to create a virtual machine of a Windows 10 laptop using Sysinternals 'Disk2vhd utility.

First I created a `vhdx` file of the laptops `C:` drive using the `Disk2vhd` utility. Afterwards I copied the `vhdx` file to my Windows 10 desktop computer and created a virtual machine in Hyper-V-Manager. The virtual machine starts and I can see the login screen but after a few seconds I am always getting a `memory management` blue screen `0xC000000F`.

Is there anything I could do to fix this problem?
Thank you in advance for your help!

**Update:** I discovered that you can also attach a `vhd` or `vhdx` file in Windows 10 through the `Computer Management` (for more information refer to this [article](https://www.nakivo.com/blog/how-to-convert-vhd-to-vmdk-a-step-by-step-guide/?utm_source=medium_taras_yefimenko)). I attached a fresh copy of the `vhdx` file i previously tried to boot in Hyper-V and everything works as expected and i can access the data stored in the `vhdx` file.

The `Computer Management` shows that the partitions: efi, windows ntfs and recovery are error free. I still don't know the reason for the continuously appearing blue screen in Hyper-V.

**Update 2:** I also learned that you can convert a `vhd` or `vhdx` file to a other file format like `vmdk` using `VBoxManage` from `VirtualBox`. I converted the `vhdx` file into a `vmdk` file and used it to create a virtual machine in `Workstation Player`. The virtual machine works flawless in `Workstation Player`. I still don't know the reason for constant blue screens in Hyper-V but at least i have a working virtual machine now. I hope this can help people with a similiar problem.

[Article that explains how to attach a vhd or vhdx file in Windows 10 and how to convert it them into a vmdk file using VBoxManage](https://www.nakivo.com/blog/how-to-convert-vhd-to-vmdk-a-step-by-step-guide/?utm_source=medium_taras_yefimenko)

Comment: If you found a solution or workaround, you can post and accept your own answer to close the discussion, not putting that in question body.

Comment: @LexLi Thank you for the reminder. I hope that a better solution can be found.

Answer (score 4):

I have tried following your route, but used [StarWind V2V Converter](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-v2v-converter).
I checked option "activate repair mode" after conversion. In Hyper-V, I created Gen 1 VM and attached resulted VHDX to it. The only have faced **0xC000000E** error during first boot. I attached Win10 is and fixed BCD. VM booted afterwards. Might help: https://codeistry.wordpress.com/2014/06/27/windows-p2v-machines-boot-error-status-0xc000000e/

P.S. P2V conversions to Workstation and VirtualBox are usually easier.